# Симуляция нескольких компьютерных мышей

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

У меня есть скрипты на **python3**, которые симулируют движения, нажатия и тд.. мыши. Для этого можно использовать, как `pywin32`(`win32api`, `win32con`), так и `pynput`, но я не смог найти возможности симулировать две мыши. Для `pywin32`, это выглядит невозможным, и для `pynput` я тоже ничего не нашёл.
Возможно ли симулировать ввод от двух мышек, используя функции этих или других библиотек?

Последний вариант - использовать одну мышь заместо двух (быстро прыгать между позициями), но это будет сильно урезать возможности.

Применение: симуляция работы приложений на андроиде, где нужно использовать несколько касаний, для управления, например два джойстика.

Comment: Как вы себе это представляете?Два курсора?
Они просто вступят конфликт еще не известно ,что произойдет...

Comment: я планирую избежать конфликта, за этим ,собственно, и обращаюсь

Comment: Не знаю можно ли так сделать...Используйте `pyautogui` для эмуляции мыши или клавиотуры.
На нем можно очень быстро перемещять мышь по экрану.

**P.S** А зачем вам это надо?

Comment: Хорошо посмотрю. Не могу сказать точно,  но похоже, multiprocessing справляется с такой задачей. Надо точнее проверить.

Comment: P.S.Я создаю бота, играющего в одну игру, и мне нужно симулировать управление

Comment: P.P.S. Я использую pynput

Comment: нет, multiprocessing не дает возможности симулировать две мыши

Comment: Не понятно зачем для этого две мыши...Ведь если играет один человек он использует одну!

Comment: Не на мобильном телефоне)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495234/how-to-simulate-touch-for-any-application-in-android

Comment: пальцы в мультитач курсор не двигают

Comment: @eri, идея в том, чтобы на компьютере запустить (через те же эмуляторы, например) андроид-приложение и иметь возможность имитировать мультитач.

Comment: а эмулятор об этом знает?) может ли эмулятор передать мультитач приложению внутри?

Comment: @eri, естественно, это подразумевается. (В том смысле, что приложение может получать несколько нажатий через эмулятор; тут может возникнуть вопрос о том, как это сделать для конкретного эмулятора)

Comment: @0dminnimda эмулятор это умеет?